# Applying CSS to input container on focus

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with a input field and a button inside. I would like the button to be hidden until the user focuses on the input.

I have tried to use the :focus pseudo-class on the containing div as I thought it would be inherited upon focusing on the input however it did not work.

Here is my html

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

And here is the css I have already tried

```
.search button {
    display: none;
}

.search:focus button {
    display: block;
}
```

Is it possible to do this without JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, you can use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JdT2C/)

```
.search input:focus + button {
    display: block;
}
```

As [FelipeAls points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571890/applying-css-to-input-container-on-focus/23571910#comment36173386_23571910), though, you can't click on the button if the focus is removed. You could therefore do something like this in addition:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g2b5p/)

```
.search button:hover,
.search button:focus {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks a lot. I will mark as answer in 13 minutes :)

Comment: Fine until you try to reach this button (edit: by tabbing)... then input hasn't focus anymore and the button gets back to its hidden state :(

Comment: @FelipeAls You are correct however this button will act as a fall-back for users with JavaScript disabled in this case, there will be another button which will override this when JavaScript is enabled so I am not too worried about it not being perfectly practical

Comment: The above works while click the button using mouse click.. but when i press the tab key the button disappears.. for that we can use the additional style..   `.search button:focus { display:block; }` ... so that while tabbing also the button becomes there..

Comment: @SoundarR Good point, I forgot about that :) Thanks for mentioning that.